# MapReduce task using channels

Tags: go

My function downloads data, parses it and returns some result. I would like to start many instances of the function concurrently and sum up the results of them. Here is my solution using `Mutex`:

```
var lock sync.Mutex
increment := func(data engine2.DownloadResult) {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    albums += data.Album
    singles += data.Single
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
foo := func(id uint) {
    defer wg.Done()
    result := engine.DownloadPlaylist(id)
    increment(*result)
}

for _, playlist := range repository.PlaylistRepository.Fetch() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go foo(playlist.Id)
}

wg.Wait()
```

As I know `channels` are recommended synchronization mechanism in Go. Can you please show me how can I rewrite this task using channels?

Comment: I am a bit... puzzled. That is not exactly a map/reduce, is it?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg, why not? I am perform some operation for each playlist (Map-step) and calculete aggregate over all playlists (Reduce-step).  For me, it is looks like as a classic MapReduce (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions using channels. One might look like this:

```
ch := make(chan *engine2.DownloadResult)
wg := sync.WaitGroup()
go func() {
   for result := range ch {
      increment_without_lock(result)
   }
}()
for _, playlist := range repository.PlaylistRepository.Fetch() {
    id := playlist.Id
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
       defer wg.Done()
       ch <- engine.DownloadPlaylist(id)
    }()
}
wg.Wait()
close(ch)
```